# MAAS deployment without formatting secondary disks

Tags: 16.04, maas, cluster

I manage a cluster of computers used for scientific computing using MAAS 2.1. Each node has a 500GB SDD that holds the OS and serves as scratch space for computation. Additionally, each node has a secondary 5TB disk that holds several terabytes of data.

When I release and deploy a machine (with the MAAS UI), all disks get formatted, meaning I have to copy data back onto the large volume (very time consuming).

Is there any way to prevent MAAS from formatting the 5TB HDDs when I have to redeploy a machine?

Thanks!